# Looking for IP Addresses of devices connected

Tags: ip, broadcast

So the problem which I got was that I was shown a HiL setup with a lot of KVM switches and other computers connected. I was asked to check if say device A was working or not. By working I mean if it was communicating or not.

My solution was to use `ifconfig` which will produce a list of devices connected to the laptop. What I tried to do was that I try to disconnect all the sockets in the hub and see if the packets would drop but nothing happened. I want to know how to single out devices just by using the command line. I mean I see four Lidar sensors connected but I don't know which one is which, how can I know which sensor is which and with what ID.

This was an interview question and I am curious to how should have I done it. Right now I am looking into `broadcast` and `trace` commands but I am not sure if I am on the right path.

Comment: "My solution was to use ifconfig which will produce a list of devices connected to the laptop" Wrong premise. `ifconfig` will produce a list of connected *network interfaces*, not devices. How are adresses assigned? Why not use `ping`/`nmap`?

Comment: How would you identify "device A" on the network? Does it have a known IP address or MAC address?